# ContinueSpan does not work for local method call in Micronaut

Tags: micronaut, zipkin

I have adapted the sample from Micronaut Users Guide V1.2.10 chapter Tracing Annotations.

```
@NewSpan("hello-world") 
public String hello(@SpanTag("person.name") String name) { 
    return greet("Hello " + name);
}

@ContinueSpan 
public String greet(@SpanTag("hello.greeting") String greet) {
    return greet;
}
```

My code looks that like:

```
@NewSpan("hello-world")
@Get("/name")
public String hello(@SpanTag("hello.name") String name) {

    String nameDouble = doubleName(name);

    String address = client.toBlocking()
            .retrieve(HttpRequest.GET("/address"));

    return "Hello world " + nameDouble + " " + address;
}

@ContinueSpan
private String doubleName(@SpanTag("doubleName.name")String name) {
    return name + " " + name;
}

@Get("/address")
@ContinueSpan
public String address() {
    return "Some address";
}
```

The question is, why the call for method doubleName is not logged to zipkin (at least it does not show up in the zipkin GUI). The REST call to address() is logged. Do only REST calls get logged and no local method calls? Actually I don't think that's that the case because the Users Guides sample tells that this should work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? I mean, activate the proper packages and check if its doing it well. Another thing you can do is try it fi Jaeger and see if it's a matter of zipkin GUI

Answer (score 1):

The `doubleName` method is private. Micronaut cannot apply AOP annotations (like `ContinueSpan` to private methods.

Comment: I made method doubleName public but it still is not listen in zipkin GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Are these methods on a bean (`Singleton`, etc.)? I have found the span annotations only get applied on beans properly. I had to refactor some of my code to create beans from `Factory`s or such.